# Google custom search engine result counts changing as results are paged

Tags: google-custom-search

I have implemented a Google custom search engine in a website. When searching a word, it brings out results like totalResults - 168 and I am retrieving it by 10 results per page.

Up to 60 results it works fine, but in the 7th page, the total results from Google api response changes to a total of 67.

I am using a free version of the Google custom search API. I don't know whether it is working correctly or not. Please provide me a solution if it is wrong or correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of google search behaviour well explained in following links.

https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/customsearch/D4--2TfYk9A

https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/customsearch/SjlrUMa-X-k